# Type of types in Scala

Tags: scala, types, casting

Is it possible in Scala to pass a type to a function as an argument (along with other parameters) and return an object of that type?

For example, let's say I have n different classes where each of them has its own members. I want some thing like:

```
def Make(T:TypeOfPossibleClasses):T={
   val A= new T()
   // do some thing on A
   A
}
```

I'm aware of `Manifest`, and I know that I can do this by matching manifest of `T` with manifest of all possible classes of interest. But, I may have too many classes (and in fact new class types may get introduced later on).

Does Scala support generic type passing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose you can act like in java

```
def make[T](clz: Class[T]): T = clz.newInstance() // class should have default constructor

make(classOf[String])
```

or use `Manifest` instance:

```
def make[T](implicit m : Manifest[T]): T =
  m.runtimeClass.asInstanceOf[Class[T]].newInstance()

make[String] // res0: String = ""

make[AnyRef] // res1: AnyRef = java.lang.Object@7794ed7a
```

Comment: Thanks! How would you call it then?, say I want to make an Int, does it work like this: `val i = make(Int)`?

Comment: @Alt I added code sample and wrote limitations of this approach. Don't forget that some classes can't instantiate without obligatory parameters.

Comment: Consider using `TypeTag` instead of `Manifest` http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/typetags-manifests.html

Comment: @SergeyLagutin: Thanks!

Comment: @Aivean: Can you please elaborate on `TypeTag` a little bit?

Comment: @Alt Just check [this link](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/typetags-manifests.html). `TypeTag` is a replacement of `Manifest` for the scala 2.10+. It provides richer reflection functionality. Use it in the same way as `Manifest` is used in Sergey Lagutin's example.